# Смещение тени элемента относительно курсора

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой прелоадер, который относительно мышки меняет тень, но тень уходит слишком далеко, нужно уменьшить.

Должно быть как тут https://kalpa.parmigiani.com/en

Идея и код взята отсюда, но там код в минимизированном в виде, поэтому не получилось полностью взять:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  var preloader = document.querySelector('.preload_percent');

  var i = preloader.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = Math.round(Math.floor(-(i.left + i.width)) / 11),
    y = Math.round(Math.floor(-(i.top + i.height)) / 9.5),
    blur;

  x += (event.screenX - x) / 10;
  y += (event.screenY - y) / 10;

  blur = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
  blur = Math.min(Math.max((blur / 5), 5), 20);

  $(preloader).css('filter', 'drop-shadow(' + -x + 'px ' + -y + 'px ' + blur + 'px rgba(100,100,100,0.25))');
});
```

```css
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: -10;
}

.preloader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.preloader.loading {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 20;
}

.preloader .preload_percent {
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  font-size: 280px;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(15px 20px 20px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2));
  filter: drop-shadow(15px 20px 20px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2));
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader loading">
  <div class="preload_percent">99</div>
</div>
```

[Ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hattam/pen/QJVVxv?editors=0010)

Comment: https://codepen.io/hattam/pen/QJVVxv?editors=0010

Answer (score 1):

Тут `x += (event.screenX - x) / 10;    y += (event.screenY - y) / 10;` вместо 10 поставте например 30 будет `x += (event.screenX - x) / 30;  y += (event.screenY - y) / 30;`. Меняя коефициент вы меняете уровень отдаления тени.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  var preloader = document.querySelector('.preload_percent');

  var i = preloader.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = Math.round(Math.floor(-(i.left + i.width)) / 11),
    y = Math.round(Math.floor(-(i.top + i.height)) / 9.5),
    blur;

  x += (event.screenX - x) / 30;
  y += (event.screenY - y) / 30;

  blur = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
  blur = Math.min(Math.max((blur / 5), 5), 20);

  $(preloader).css('filter', 'drop-shadow(' + -x + 'px ' + -y + 'px ' + blur + 'px rgba(100,100,100,0.25))');
});
```

```css
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: -10;
}

.preloader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.preloader.loading {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 20;
}

.preloader .preload_percent {
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  font-size: 280px;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(15px 20px 20px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2));
  filter: drop-shadow(15px 20px 20px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2));
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader loading">
  <div class="preload_percent">99</div>
</div>
```

Comment: если было бы всё так просто, то вопрос не возник бы, я думаю. Попробуйте, после изменения коэффициентов, раскрыть на полную страницу и отвести курсор вправо до упора - тень влево практически не сдвигается, хотя в другую сторону всё отлично работает. _Эх, нет времени сейчас, т.ч. оставлю на Вас решение._

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/briangonzalez/pen/Btmpe)

```js
window.requestAnimFrame = function () {
  return function (callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000);
  };
}();

$(document).ready(function () {

  var $shadow = $('#shadow');
  var shadowLimit = 200;
  var moveEvent = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? "touchmove" : "mousemove";

  (function animloop() {
    requestAnimFrame(animloop);

    $(window).bind(moveEvent, function (ev) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var w = $this.width();
      var h = $this.height();
      var center = { x: w / 2, y: h / 2 };

      var evX = moveEvent == 'touchmove' ? ev.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX : ev.clientX;
      var evY = moveEvent == 'touchmove' ? ev.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY : ev.clientY;

      var shadowX = (center.x - evX) / 10;
      var shadowY = (center.y - evY) / 10;

      shadowX = shadowX > shadowLimit ? shadowLimit : shadowX;
      shadowX = shadowX < shadowLimit * -1 ? shadowLimit * -1 : shadowX;
      shadowY = shadowY > shadowLimit ? shadowLimit : shadowY;
      shadowY = shadowY < shadowLimit * -1 ? shadowLimit * -1 : shadowY;

      $shadow.css({ textShadow: Math.ceil(shadowX) + 'px ' + Math.ceil(shadowY) + 'px ' + Math.abs(shadowX * shadowY) / 100 + 'px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)' });


    });
  })();


});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+SC:400,700,900);
body {
  background: #c41753;
  color: #323232;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px rgba(196, 23, 83, 0.1);
  -moz-transition: text-shadow 20ms;
  -o-transition: text-shadow 20ms;
  -webkit-transition: text-shadow 20ms;
  transition: text-shadow 20ms;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(196, 23, 83, 0.5);
}
h1 .top, h1 .bottom {
  font-family: 'Alegreya SC';
}
h1 .top {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 46px;
}
h1 .bottom {
  font-size: 52px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
h1 .bottom .us {
  font-weight: 900;
}
h1 .shadow {
  font-size: 130px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  line-height: 80px;
}
h1 .white {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id='shadow'>
  <span class='top'>
    somewhat
    <span class='white'>
      creepy
      when your
    </span>
  </span>
  <div class='shadow'>
    SHADOW
  </div>
  <span class='bottom'>
    follows
    <span class='us'>
      you & me
    </span>
    around
  </span>
</h1>
```