# CSS, JS анимация тени

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Как сделать такую же анимацию при hover как на этом сайте - https://unitk.ai/ с помощью JS или CSS?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Смещение тени элемента относительно курсора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912541/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого используется text-shadow.

```css
span
{
  display: block;
  margin: 25px;

  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: text-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
}

span:hover
{
  text-shadow: rgb(3 6 7) 0px 0px 4px, rgb(3 6 7) 10px 10px 10px, rgb(3 6 7) -10px -10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<span>TEST</span>
```

Comment: Я думаю тут требуется направление тени относительно курсора.

Comment: спасибо большое!